# Prove or disprove $\int f^2\int g^2\geq (\int fg)^2$ proof verify

Tags: real-analysis

I require some assistance on real analysis. I'm trying to understand when I got a question incorrect on the exam but wasn't able to figure it out. Help would be appreciated.

The question states,

> Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous (Riemann) integrable functions on an interval $[a,b]$, prove or disprove
>   $$
> \left(\int_{[a,b]} f(x)g(x)dx\right)^2\leq\left(\int_{[a,b]} \big[f(x)\big]^2dx\right)\left(\int_{[a,b]} \big[g(x)\big]^2dx\right).
> $$

I erroneously answered

> Let $f=0.5$ and $g=1$ on $[0,2]$, note that
>   $$
> 1=\left(\int_{[0,2]}f(x)g(x)dx\right)^2\not\leq\left(\int_{[0,2]} \big[f(x)\big]^2dx\right)\left(\int_{[0,2]} \big[g(x)\big]^2dx\right)=0.5.
> $$

I know how to prove it now but I'm so confused as to where my logic failed, maybe it's very trivial I just don't see it. Ironically I got the second part correct for the counterpart on Lebesgue integrable functions (on measurable sets with finite measure of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $\int_0^2 f(x)^2\textrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\int_0^2 g(x)^2\textrm{d}x=2,$ so their product is $1$, not $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Oh my gosh I can't believe I scrached my head so hard and couldn't see this. Thanks!

Comment: Also, before writing the integral lines, you're only defining your functions on $[0,1]$, but I assume you just mean the constant functions.

Comment: Apologies typo, has been corrected to reflect that. =)